# Correlated subquery in a select statement with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, correlated-subquery

I have a select query with group by and the select list has a correlated sub-query in it. This query returns the correct results. My question is how is this query working. Shouldn't the sub-query be part of the group by list? Could someone please explain the mechanics behind it? Thank you!

```
Select a.column1
      ,Max(a.column2)                         'MaxValue'
      ,Min(a.column2)                         'MinValue'
      ,(Select top 1 Column c
          From table A  a_s
         Where a_s.column1 = a.column1
           and a_s.ver <> 0
        )                                     'ColumnCValue'
  From tableA a
 Group by a.column1
```

Comment: FYI use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is usually a logic flaw. And usually the order of rows in a resultset matters - meaning your main query should probably have an ORDER BY clause. Grouping often leads to rows in the order you desire, but that is an artifact of the execution plan. It is not guaranteed.

Comment: Aside: you can do this without a subquery using window functions and conditional aggregation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary.  This is the correlated subquery:

```
(Select top 1 Column c
 From table A  a_s
 Where a_s.column1 = a.column1 and
-------^
       a_s.ver <> 0
)
```

The key is that the correlation clause is using `a.column1`.  And that column is an aggregation column.  In effect, the correlated subquery is run *after* the aggregation, so it can only use columns and expressions available after aggregation.  And you are doing that, so your expression is fine.